# Add or not add pop/smtp to mail server

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

When resolving my email domain and setting up the mail on an email client, I realized both setting POP to **pop.mx.server.com** and SMTP to **smtp.mx.server.com** works just as well as setting both POP and SMTP to **mx.server.com**, as long as I kept both the domain resolution and the email client preferences consistent.

Are they identical?

Comment: probably a redirect at the server end. Mine used to be the same, years ago.

Comment: but how would the server know where to redirect? by port no?

Comment: I have no clue, sorry, just reporting an anecdotal memory

Comment: Almost certainly by port. POP3 and IMAP (sending and receiving, secure and non-secure) all use separate ports.

Answer (score 0):

It's largely irrelevant if it's your own mail serve for personal user. All these do are point to an IP address.

When you are running email for others, they sometimes expect an smtp and pop3 name - and in large orgs SMTP and POP3 are sometimes handled differently - So if this is someone else's mail server use the suggested values as it gives them freedom to better manage their system without breaking things.